# How to apply wordpress shortcode in sidebar using fishpig extension in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress

I've installed fishpig extension in magento for wordpress blog. But I'm not able to apply shortcode in sidebar. But its works in post.

Please help me on this situation.